# Masonry.js not displaying correctly in firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, jquery-masonry, masonry

I'm using masonry.js version 2 (?) on a website [www.saracobbsphotography.co.uk](http://www.saracobbsphotography.co.uk) and it's displaying as expected in IE, Chrome and Safari, but not in Firefox 33.0.1

It may not be the masonry plugin that's causing the problem, but Firefox is only displaying this page (index.html) incorrectly and it's the one that uses masonry.

If anyone would have a look at the website in Firefox and has a potential solution, would be great to hear from you.

Thanks

Comment: Can you just check if it works if you add `float: left;` to the css in class `#masonry-section` (main.css line 354) ?

Comment: That was it. Thanks matthias_h! Thought I'd checked that - obviously not! Thanks again.

Comment: Just noticed at http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/198733/how-to-mark-comment-as-answer#answer-198734 that the common protocol should be to post the comment as an answer to get accepted (instead of deleting the question as suggested previously) so the question is marked as closed. Sorry for previous false advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `float; left` to the css in class `#masonry-section` (main.css line 354).